# Using WorksheetFunction.Left returns error

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet-function

Some simple things are not working in my VBA. For example none `WorksheetFunction` is working.
For example:

```
Sub ReturnLeft()
    MsgBox Application.WorksheetFunction.Left("ABC", 1)
End Sub
```

When I run this code, I will get

> Run-time error 438.

I know there is method `Left` in VBA but I need to find out what is the problem with `WorksheetFunction`. Can some library be broken?

Answer (score 1):

You must use the [Left function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/left-function) of VBA because `WorksheetFunction.Left` does not exist:

```
Sub ReturnLeft()
    MsgBox Left$("ABC", 1)
End Sub
```

Also see [WorksheetFunction object - Methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction#methods) for a list of existing methods.

Comment: I used left only as an example. The trouble is that none WorksheetFunction is working.

Comment: Well you chose a very bad example then, `WorksheetFunction.Left` does definitely not exist and therefore cannot work. Which one does not work too? Show an exact example and the code how you use it (see [mcve]) edit your original question accordingly.

Comment: This page misleaded me because it says that it exists.  https://www.automateexcel.com/vba/worksheet-functions-in-macro/

Comment: @marianzigo Always refer to the official Microsoft documentation ^^. Actually the error message is pretty clear. Error 438 says *"The object does not support this property or method"* which exactly means the object `WorksheetFunction` does not have the method `Left`. That's all I can say about `WorksheetFunction.Left`.